# python canopy prompt mode

Tags: python, mode, canopy

Updated with information I forgot to include:

Canopy Version: 1.7.4.3348 (64 bit)

Python version: '2.7.11 | 64-bit | (default, Jun 11 2016, 11:33:47) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]'

Also: This problem only started a few days ago, but it's pretty irritating. It could be the network guys are doing something, or it could be I've altered my environment somehow without realizing it.

I have the habitual problem in Canopy that for some reason the prompt in the immediate window acts weird.  It lets me type, but doesn't do anything and doesn't seem to advance to the next command.

```
Welcome to Canopy's interactive data-analysis environment!'t' not in 'tf'
Type '?' for more information.

...:
...:
n [1]: %run "C:\Projects\MyProject\MyProgram.py"

Enter (T)est or (F)ull or (Q)uit: t

How many rows to process: d

't' not in 'tf'
Out[2]: False

'a' not in 'tf'
Out[3]: True
In [4]: 
...:
...:
...:
```

The only way I can get past this is to restart the kernel.  I think something in my program might be causing this.  Not sure what.  Don't want to put the whole thing here.  Anyone had this problem and know what kind of thing might cause it?

Also, what is this "mode" called and is there a way to get back to a regular "mode" without restarting the kernel?

Comment: This is not a mode. This is a bug or system configuration problem. Also, you don't say what version of Canopy you are using, or (if 2.x) what version of Python you are running.

Comment: I think it's a version problem.  I think going to update later next week after my crunch. tx,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your firewall might be blocking ipython's communication with its kernel. Try disconnecting from the internet, disabling your firewall, and trying again. If this solves the problem then you'll need to configure your firewall not to block localhost, or use a smarter firewall program.

Comment: That sounds like a plan.  I don't control the firewall where I work, but if I can narrow things down, maybe the network guys can cut me a break.  First I'm going to wait to do an update to the most recent version of canopy/python late next week.

Comment: During upgrade of python, I found there was a firewall issue at this end that was not reported in the previous version.  Our IT guys resolved that and I've been running for several days now without incident, tx